# Where condition as variable in results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Right now I have this Moongose query using geo-spatial data:

```
Locations.find({
    loc: {
        $geoWithin: {
            $centerSphere: [[lng, lat], radius / 6378.1],
        },
    }
}, cb);
```

It works well, but my question is how to get all `Location` documents, where each one would have a boolean variable, showing if it that particular document is within specified circle from where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that using the aggregation [**`$project`**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjegq3L4YfGAhUD6CwKHfAFANk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mongodb.org%2Fmanual%2Freference%2Foperator%2Faggregation%2Fproject&ei=NY95VZ6UA4PQswHwi4DIDQ&usg=AFQjCNFgYl_3aM1HWDoBv0Bn7e8ghdGaag&sig2=HC76fbWE1DOZlG6ncLUe_Q) stage, to project a condition as an additional field in the resulting document. Unfortunately, no GeoSpatial operators are defined for the aggregation framework, thus you cannot achieve your goal in a single MongoDB query.

If making two queries is ok for you you may try the following option:

```
db.locations.aggregate([
    {$match: {
                loc: {
                        $geoWithin: {
                                       $centerSphere: [[lng, lat], radius / 6378.1],
                                    },
                     }
              }
     },
     {$project: 
                 {
                     ...
                     // all of your fields
                     ...
                     isWithin: true
                 }
     }                  
])
```

And do the same thing in reverse, to match the document that are not within, and set `isWithin` to `false`. This will artificially get you the result you desired.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What do you mean by reversing? I have tried your code, but `isWithin` is `undefined`.